# AWS - get autoscaling names for use with Capistrano

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, capistrano3

I am trying to setup a remote deployment with Capistrano on the Amazon Cloud.

The idea : I SSH to a random machine of the autoscaling group and I want to deploy to all the other machines from there. In order to do that I need to get the names of the other instances so I can define the Capistrano servers I want to deploy to

I have installed the Ruby sdk but I cannot figure out the best way to retrieve the instances names (taking advantage that I am on the VPN).

I have actually two possibilities : either find the instances by tags (I have tagged them with "production") or by the ID of the autoscaling group.

I don't want to use other "big guns" like Chef, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After reading too much documentation

Two strategies : retrieve the dns names by autoscaling group OR by tags

## By Tags

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new

instances_tagged = ec2.describe_instances(
  dry_run: false,
  filters: [
    {
      name: 'tag:environment',
      values: ['production'],
    },
    {
      name: 'tag:stack',
      values: ['rails'],
    }
  ],
)

dns_tagged = instances_tagged.reservations[0].instances.map(&:private_dns_name)
```

## By Autoscaling group

```
as = Aws::AutoScaling::Client.new
instances_of_as =  as.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
  auto_scaling_group_names: ['Autoscaling-Group-Name'],
  max_records: 1,
).auto_scaling_groups[0].instances

if instances_of_as.empty?
  autoscaling_dns = []
else 
  instances_ids = instances_of_as.map(&:instance_id)
  autoscaling_dns = instance_ids.map do |instance_id|
    ec2.instances[instance_id].private_dns_name
  end
end
```